# Automate Connect-AzureAD Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-powershell-v2

I created a script using powershell that connect to AzureAD and it was working fine using the following:

```
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId
```

The sign in window pops up and I am able to successfully connect. However, I need to setup the script to run automatically so I found this code to do it:

```
# Set Configs
$TenantId = "<tenant id>"
$AzureUser = "<user>" 
$AzurePass = Get-Content "cred.txt" | ConvertTo-SecureString

# Connect to Azure AD
$AzureCred = New-Object -TypeName "System.Management.Automation.PSCredential" -ArgumentList $AzureUser, $AzurePass
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. I use the following to generate my cred.txt file:

```
Read-Host -assecurestring | convertfrom-securestring | out-file C:\cred.txt
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: The character set
>   provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string
>   using an invalid character set. At line:9 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
>   Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred. At line:9 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AggregateException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
>   Connect-AzureAD : The character set provided in ContentType is
>   invalid. Cannot read content as string using an invalid character set.
>   At line:9 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
>   Connect-AzureAD : '"utf-8"' is not a supported encoding name. For
>   information on defining a custom encoding, see the documentation for
>   the Encoding.RegisterProvider method. Parameter name: name At line:9
>   char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], ArgumentException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Connect-AzureAD,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD
>   Connect-AzureAD : One or more errors occurred.: The character set
>   provided in ContentType is invalid. Cannot read content as string
>   using an invalid character set. At line:9 char:1
>   + Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $TenantId -Credential $AzureCred
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-AzureAD], AadAuthenticationFailedException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.AadAuthenticationFailedException,Microsoft.Open.Azure.AD.CommonLibrary.ConnectAzureAD

I logged in on a different tenant using the same script and it was working fine. It is just not working to the tenant that has federation on. Any workaround for this aside from turning off federation?

Comment: seems ok, tested it and working fine, maybe a typo?

Comment: If it is working on your end, it might be due to our environment. We have federation turned on in our tenant, not sure if that is causing the issue.

Comment: Does your password (**which should be saved _AS_ securestring, not plaintext and converted to one**) contain any very special chars?

Comment: @Clijsters only letter and numbers

Comment: @sparkiedev Your script works fine for me. Your account is an Azure AD account and you don't enable multi-factor authentication?

Comment: MFA is not enabled on our tenant, just federation